# Appium Web Driver Agent installation failure on iOS 15.5 with Xcode 13.4.1 and Appium 1.22.3

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios

I am trying run automation on real device with iOS 15.5. I am not able to install the webdriveragent on the device. I have followed the steps mentioned in [XCUITest Real Devices](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/)

I can manually sign and build using Xcode but while using Appium Inspector to run automation, I am getting Xcode build error 65 "Unable to sign node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/webdriveragent project file".

Also, under node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent, when I try to open the webdriveragent project, I get project is locked/permission denied notification. Is that expected ?

I started noticing this with iOS 15.5 and Xcode 13.4.1. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.